# What to do if "publisher" and "author" property have the same value?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am implementing structured data into my website. When I consider Schema.org’s `Article`, `publisher` and `author` is the same `Organization`.

Is it a good practice to duplicate it in both properties? I am using JSON-LD to implement it.

Comment: What else would you do in that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON-LD (in contrast to Microdata and RDFa), you have no choice other than to duplicate it.

However, you don’t necessarily have to provide the full `Organization` item in both places. Give your `Organization` a URI with `@id`, and then reference this URI in the other place:

```json
"author": {
  "@type": "Organization",
  "@id": "/#org",
  "url": "/",
  "name": "Nosek Inc.",
  "description": "Great organization"
},
"publisher": {"@id": "/#org"}
```

It often make sense to provide/duplicate at least some properties, though, e.g., important ones like `@type`, `name`, `url` etc.:

```json
"publisher": {
  "@type": "Organization",
  "@id": "/#org",
  "name": "Nosek Inc."
}
```